# ICEfaces radio buttons

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

ICEFaces has strict restriction of closing every inner tag within the outer tag. But when creating a table layout how to incorporate various radiobuttons within different columns of the table.

Comment: Note that this "restriction" is not ICEFaces specific. This is XML/XHTML specific. I by the way do not see/understand the functional requirement. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 3):

Use the spread layout and define the radio buttons individually.

So use first:

```
<ice:selectOneRadio id="myGroup" layout="spread" />
```

And define the radio buttons wherever you want.

```
<ice:radio for="myGroup" />
```

See:
http://www.icefaces.org/docs/latest/tld/ice/selectOneRadio.html 
http://www.icefaces.org/docs/latest/tld/ice/radio.html